# mongodb mapreduce function does not provide skip functionality, is their any solution to this?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Mongodb mapreduce function does not provide any way to skip record from database like find function. It has functionality of query, sort & limit options. But I want to skip some records from the database, and I am not getting any way to it. please provide solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ideally a well-structured map-reduce query would allow you to skip particular documents in your collection.

Alternatively, as Sergio points out, you can simply not emit particular documents in map(). Using scope to define a global counter variable is one way to restrict emit to a specified range of documents. As an example, to skip the first 20 docs that are sorted by ObjectID (and thus, sorted by insertion time):

```
db.collection_name.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: example_output, sort: {id:-1}, scope: "var counter=0")};
```

Map function:

```
function(){
    counter ++;
    if (counter > 20){
        emit(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure since which version this feature is available, but certainly in MongoDB 2.6 the [`mapReduce()` function provides `query` parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce):

> `query` : *document*
>
> Optional. Specifies the selection criteria using query operators for determining the documents input to the map
>   function.

**Example**

Consider the following map-reduce operations on a collection orders that contains documents of the following prototype:

```
{
     _id: ObjectId("50a8240b927d5d8b5891743c"),
     cust_id: "abc123",
     ord_date: new Date("Oct 04, 2012"),
     status: 'A',
     price: 25,
     items: [ { sku: "mmm", qty: 5, price: 2.5 },
              { sku: "nnn", qty: 5, price: 2.5 } ]
}
```

Perform the map-reduce operation on the orders collection using the mapFunction2, reduceFunction2, and finalizeFunction2 functions.

```
db.orders.mapReduce( mapFunction2,
                 reduceFunction2,
                 {
                   out: { merge: "map_reduce_example" },
                   query: { ord_date:
                              { $gt: new Date('01/01/2012') }
                          },
                   finalize: finalizeFunction2
                 }
               )
```

This operation uses the query field to select only those documents with `ord_date` greater than `new Date(01/01/2012)`. Then it output the results to a collection `map_reduce_example`. If the `map_reduce_example` collection already exists, the operation will merge the existing contents with the results of this map-reduce operation.